# twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable after trying reactor.connectTCP to another IP adress

Tags: python, pyqt4, twisted

I need to open more than one instances through rdp. For this challenge I use rdpy library and its example https://github.com/citronneur/rdpy/blob/master/bin/rdpy-rdpscreenshot.py. First rdp connect and PyQt window is being opened and closed successfully but after trying to open the second window i' m getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/R.Halyuta/Downloads/rdpy-master/rdpy-master/bin/rdpy-rdpclient.py", line 265, in <module>
    create_rpds(i["Password"].encode('utf-8'), i["IpAddress"].encode('utf-8'))
  File "C:/Users/R.Halyuta/Downloads/rdpy-master/rdpy-master/bin/rdpy-rdpclient.py", line 225, in create_rpds
    reactor.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\qtreactor\qt4base.py", line 281, in run
    self.runReturn()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\qtreactor\qt4base.py", line 273, in runReturn
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1222, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 730, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable
```

Are there any solutions for my issue?
Here is my code:

```
import threading
import time
import sys, os, getopt, socket
import json
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from rdpy.ui.qt4 import RDPClientQt
from rdpy.protocol.rdp import rdp
from rdpy.core.error import RDPSecurityNegoFail
from rdpy.core import rss
from twisted.internet import error
import rdpy.core.log as log

log._LOG_LEVEL = log.Level.INFO


class RDPClientQtRecorder(RDPClientQt):
    """
    @summary: Widget with record session
    """

    def __init__(self, controller, width, height, rssRecorder):
        """
        @param controller: {RDPClientController} RDP controller
        @param width: {int} width of widget
        @param height: {int} height of widget
        @param rssRecorder: {rss.FileRecorder}
        """
        RDPClientQt.__init__(self, controller, width, height)
        self._screensize = width, height
        self._rssRecorder = rssRecorder

    def onUpdate(self, destLeft, destTop, destRight, destBottom, width, height, bitsPerPixel, isCompress, data):
        """
        @summary: Notify bitmap update
        @param destLeft: {int} xmin position
        @param destTop: {int} ymin position
        @param destRight: {int} xmax position because RDP can send bitmap with padding
        @param destBottom: {int} ymax position because RDP can send bitmap with padding
        @param width: {int} width of bitmap
        @param height: {int} height of bitmap
        @param bitsPerPixel: {int} number of bit per pixel
        @param isCompress: {bool} use RLE compression
        @param data: {str} bitmap data
        """
        # record update
        self._rssRecorder.update(destLeft, destTop, destRight, destBottom, width, height, bitsPerPixel,
                                 rss.UpdateFormat.BMP if isCompress else rss.UpdateFormat.RAW, data)
        RDPClientQt.onUpdate(self, destLeft, destTop, destRight, destBottom, width, height, bitsPerPixel, isCompress,
                             data)

    def onReady(self):
        """
        @summary: Call when stack is ready
        """
        self._rssRecorder.screen(self._screensize[0], self._screensize[1], self._controller.getColorDepth())
        RDPClientQt.onReady(self)

    def onClose(self):
        """
        @summary: Call when stack is close
        """
        self._rssRecorder.close()
        RDPClientQt.onClose(self)

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        """
        @summary: Convert Qt close widget event into close stack event
        @param e: QCloseEvent
        """
        self._rssRecorder.close()
        RDPClientQt.closeEvent(self, e)


class RDPClientQtFactory(rdp.ClientFactory):
    """
    @summary: Factory create a RDP GUI client
    """

    def __init__(self, width, height, username, password, domain, fullscreen, keyboardLayout, optimized, security,
                 recodedPath):
        """
        @param width: {integer} width of client
        @param heigth: {integer} heigth of client
        @param username: {str} username present to the server
        @param password: {str} password present to the server
        @param domain: {str} microsoft domain
        @param fullscreen: {bool} show widget in fullscreen mode
        @param keyboardLayout: {str} (fr|en) keyboard layout
        @param optimized: {bool} enable optimized session orders
        @param security: {str} (ssl | rdp | nego)
        @param recodedPath: {str | None} Rss file Path
        """
        self._width = width
        self._height = height
        self._username = username
        self._passwod = password
        self._domain = domain
        self._fullscreen = fullscreen
        self._keyboardLayout = keyboardLayout
        self._optimized = optimized
        self._nego = security == "nego"
        self._recodedPath = recodedPath
        if self._nego:
            # compute start nego nla need credentials
            if username != "" and password != "":
                self._security = rdp.SecurityLevel.RDP_LEVEL_NLA
            else:
                self._security = rdp.SecurityLevel.RDP_LEVEL_SSL
        else:
            self._security = security
        self._w = None

    def buildObserver(self, controller, addr):
        """
        @summary:  Build RFB observer
                    We use a RDPClientQt as RDP observer
        @param controller: build factory and needed by observer
        @param addr: destination address
        @return: RDPClientQt
        """
        # create client observer
        if self._recodedPath is None:
            self._client = RDPClientQt(controller, self._width, self._height)
        else:
            self._client = RDPClientQtRecorder(controller, self._width, self._height,
                                               rss.createRecorder(self._recodedPath))
        # create qt widget
        self._w = self._client.getWidget()
        self._w.setWindowTitle('rdpy-rdpclient')
        if self._fullscreen:
            self._w.showFullScreen()
        else:
            self._w.show()
            self._w.show()
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10000, self._w.close)
        controller.setUsername(self._username)
        controller.setPassword(self._passwod)
        controller.setDomain(self._domain)
        controller.setKeyboardLayout(self._keyboardLayout)
        controller.setHostname(socket.gethostname())
        if self._optimized:
            controller.setPerformanceSession()
        controller.setSecurityLevel(self._security)

        return self._client

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        # from twisted.internet import reactor
        """
        @summary: Connection lost event
        @param connector: twisted connector use for rdp connection (use reconnect to restart connection)
        @param reason: str use to advertise reason of lost connection
        """
        # try reconnect with basic RDP security
        if reason.type == RDPSecurityNegoFail and self._nego:
            # stop nego
            log.info("due to security nego error back to standard RDP security layer")
            self._nego = False
            self._security = rdp.SecurityLevel.RDP_LEVEL_RDP
            self._client._widget.hide()
            connector.connect()
            return
        log.info("Lost connection : %s" % reason)
        reactor.stop()
        app.exit()

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        """
        @summary: Connection failed event
        @param connector: twisted connector use for rdp connection (use reconnect to restart connection)
        @param reason: str use to advertise reason of lost connection
        """
        # from twisted.internet import reactor
        log.info("Connection failed : %s" % reason)
        reactor.stop()
        app.exit()


def autoDetectKeyboardLayout():
    """
    @summary: try to auto detect keyboard layout
    """
    try:
        if os.name == 'posix':
            from subprocess import check_output
            result = check_output(["setxkbmap", "-print"])
            if 'azerty' in result:
                return "fr"
        elif os.name == 'nt':
            import win32api, win32con, win32process
            from ctypes import windll
            w = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
            tid = windll.user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(w, 0)
            result = windll.user32.GetKeyboardLayout(tid)
            log.info(result)
            if result == 0x40c040c:
                return "fr"
    except Exception as e:
        log.info("failed to auto detect keyboard layout " + str(e))
        pass
    return "en"


def create_rpds(passw, ip):
    keyboardLayout = autoDetectKeyboardLayout()
    domain = ""
    fullscreen = False
    optimized = False
    recodedPath = None
    width = 1024
    height = 800

    if fullscreen:
        width = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry().width()
        height = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry().height()

    log.info("keyboard layout set to %s" % keyboardLayout)

    connector = reactor.connectTCP(ip, 3389,
                                   RDPClientQtFactory(width, height, "Administrator", passw, domain, fullscreen,
                                                      keyboardLayout,
                                                      optimized, "nego", recodedPath))
    reactor.run()
    # reactor.runReturn()
    # print i
    # tr.start()
    app.exec_()

    # reactor.callLater(5000, create_rpds)
    # time.sleep(10)
    # connector.disconnect()
    # reactor.stop()
    #print 'gfgddsfdsfsdffgfd'


def exits():
    # time.sleep(10)
    print "before stop"
    reactor.stop()
    # del(reactor)

    print "after stop"
    # time.sleep(10)
    print "before app_ehit"

    app.exit()
    print "after app"


import qt4reactor

qt4reactor.install()

with open('json_file.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
for i in data:
    from twisted.internet import reactor

    create_rpds(i["Password"].encode('utf-8'), i["IpAddress"].encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: `reactor.run()` should not be called in a loop like the way you have it. It should only be run once.

Comment: @notorious.no thanks, i get it